# Cannot find base64 encoded string

Tags: character-encoding, salesforce, apex-code

I have a MS Doc file and I have converted it from Blob to Base64 encoded string. It contains a string in it as: `<z></z>`

And I have base64 encoded string for this: `<z></z>`

But when I search it in the above string converted from blob data then I am not able to find it!!

Can you guide me what I am doing wrong:

```
Blob beforeblob1 = Blob.valueOf(vDovMerge.Merge_Text__c);
    String vDovMergeBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(beforeblob1 );

    String v = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(vDoc.Body);
    system.debug('****v****'+v);
    Blob beforeblob = Blob.valueOf('<z></z>');
    String rep = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(beforeblob );
    system.debug('****rep****'+rep );
    v = v.replace(rep ,vDovMergeBlob );
    system.debug('****v****'+v);
```

Answer (score 2):

Base64-encoding converts 3 bytes of input to 4 bytes of output. So when encoding `<z></z>` only it is sure to start as the first byte of the block to be encoded. When encoding it as part of a larger data-block it may end up starting as the second or third byte to be encoded thus producing totally different output - that even depends on the data surrounding your block.

Example:
Assuming ASCII-encoding 
encoding `<z></z>` results in `PHo+PC96Pg==`
encoding `a<z></z>`results in `YTx6Pjwvej4=`
encoding `aa<z></z>` results in `YWE8ej48L3o+`
encoding `aaa<z></z>` results in `YWFhPHo+PC96Pg==` which again contains the original encoding since it starts on a 3-byte-boundary.

So the only way to search the base64-encoded data would be to treat it as a bit-stream and search for the bit-pattern of `<z></z>` without respect to byte-boundaries - doesn't sound like a lot of fun to me :-(

Comment: Hi Thanks, for the insight.. but how can I get a for loop on blob as there is no byte datatype in Apex salesforce!!